# What is the correct way to check if two ISets have the same entities

Tags: c#, .net, performance, nhibernate

I wish to implement Equals for the following class where the order of Subs is not relevant

```
class Entity {
   ISet<SubEntity> Subs;
}
```

This may be called in an inner loop comparing several thousand of entities, so performance may be an issue.

From my cursory exploration I believe the best option is `other.Subs.ExclusiveOr(Subs).IsEmpty` . Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a correct way to implement the required functionality. If performance becomes an issue, (after profiling of course), then you can consider adding some heuristics to determining if two sets have the same elements. Jon Skeet has a blog series about optimizing LINQ to Objects, you may look at [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+JonSkeetCodingBlog+%28Jon+Skeet%27s+Coding+Blog%29). It investigates the operation of the Intersect method which you can use to determine set equality.